# Isomorphism between two generalized quaternions algebras

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

Suppose $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ are distinct primes that are congruent to $3\;(mod\; 4)$. I would like to prove that
$$A=\left(\frac{-1,p}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)\not\simeq \left(\frac{-1,q}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)=A'.$$

Remark: This problem is the last exercise (Chapter 1) in the book Associative Algebras by Richard Pierce.

I appreciate any hint. Thank you.

Comment: What's this notation?

Comment: $A$ (resp. $A'$) is the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra with basis $\{1,i,j,k\}$ (resp. $\{1',i',j',k'\}$) and the multiplication has the relations $i^2=-1, j^2=p, ij=-ji=k$ (resp. $(i')^2=-1, (j')^2=q, (i'j')=-(j'i')=k'$.

Comment: Nice exercise. I guess you know that $A \simeq \lbrace \pmatrix{a+bi &  c+di \\ p(c-di) & a-bi}: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$ (and analogously for $A'$ with $q$)? My first idea was to show that there is no element  $x \in A$ with $x^2 = q$, but that is not true, e.g. for $p=11$ and $q=43$ we have $(i+2j)^2 = i^2+2ij+2ji+4j^2 =-1 +44 = 43$ in $A$. -- Can we use the reduced norm and its properties at this point?

Comment: I don't know what you know at this point.  Do you know how to determine if $A_p$ (tensor with $\mathbb Q_p$) is split or not?

Comment: It comes down to playing around with primes and squares in $\mathbb{Q}$, if you can use the following criterion: $\left(\frac{a,b}{K}\right)\simeq \left(\frac{a,c}{K}\right)$ if and only if $b/c$ is a norm of the extension $K(\sqrt{a})|K$.